# Is it good approach to store all ViewModels in a CoreViewModel in order to provide communication between each other?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is it good approach to store all ViewModels in a CoreViewModel in order to provide communication between each other? Or better using MVVM Light framework or something similar? (I want to have no-argument constructors)

```
public void SetView(Type view)
        {
            foreach (ViewBase openView in OpenViews)
                if (openView.GetType().Equals(view))
                {
                    currentView = openView;
                    currentView.Reset();
                    return;
                }
            currentView = Activator.CreateInstance(view) as ViewBase;
            OpenViews.Add(currentView);
        }
```

Comment: You should have a "tree" of parent/child viewmodels. "Locators" are an anti-pattern. Why do you want parameterless constructors?

Comment: Hi, I want to have parameterless constructors, beacuse I have this method in my CoreViewModel '            foreach (ViewBase openView in OpenViews)
                if (openView.GetType().Equals(view))
                {
                    currentView = openView;
                    currentView.Reset();
                    return;
                }
            currentView = Activator.CreateInstance(view) as ViewBase;'

Comment: That's very hard to read. Code really needs to go in the question. Is `ViewBase` your viewmodel base?

Comment: Interfaces are implemented, not inherited, and interface names should start with `I`, by convention. If your viewmodel has a collection of views (if it even knows that such a thing as a "view" even exists), you're in deep trouble already. That's a very bad idea. Why did you do that?

Comment: Oh, sorry it's not interface it's an abstraction class.

Comment: no, it's not a good approach.

Comment: Here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a6178b0-710b-4322-854f-59ce8e5d5b72/page-navigation-in-wpf-with-mvvm-what-is-the-best-approach?forum=wpf I have read that I can store Views in a List in my MainViewModel.

Comment: @Newb1996 By "views" do you mean controls? User interface elements of some kind? That's what "view" means in WPF-land. If you mean a viewmodel, please say "viewmodel" and name the class appropriately. This seems petty, but endless confusion and miscommunication can result from misusing terms.

Comment: Yea, my views it's a user controls. And the ViewBase it's an abstract class, wchich inherits after user control. And my views inherits after ViewBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed Plunkett suggests an approach I use, but I'll try to elaborate.

If I have an application that has several sub-controls (say a control per tab page in a tab control) that I want to use then the MainWindow view will bind to the main view's view model in XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The MainWindowViewModel will declare the sub-view models as public properties and in the constructor instantiate and assign a view model object to the property.

Then it is a simple question of binding the data context of a sub-control on to the relevant view model property of the MainWindowViewModel.

```
<Control DataContext="{Binding ExampleControlViewModel}"/>
```

Then if a sub-control further breaks down into smaller components, it will declare its own view model properties and the sub-views or sub-controls will bind appropriately.  Thus creating a hierarchy of view models that parallel the structure in your view/control hierarchy.

Since the whole tree of view models are initiated from the MainViewModel then it is possible to use Dependency Injection to pass down objects down through the hierarchy. For example, a mediator object to allow messaging between view models or a common database access service class.

If your application opens and closes sub-windows it gets more complicated. How to do that in an MVVM way is beyond the scope of my reply.  What is relevant is that you can instantiate a view programatically and inject the view model with something like this:

```
(new ExampleWindow() { DataContext = new ExampleWindowViewModel(_mediator) }).ShowDialog();
```

Where _mediator is the object I'm using for message passing between view models.